# Aggregate each element of tensor in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I have a tensor 3-D as follow:

```
A=array([[[False, False, False],
        [False, False,  True],
        [False,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True, False]]], dtype=bool)
        A.shape= (1,5,3)
```

I would like to convert it to 2-D tensor in tensorflow in graph where if 
I have a True in any element the aggregate result should be True, otherwise mush be False. Like follows:

```
output=array([[False, True, True, True, True]], dtype=bool)
output.shape= (1,5)
```

Comment: I have this solution but I guess should be a easy way: ` tf.greater (tf.reduce_sum (tf.to_int32(sss, name='ToInt32'), 2), 0) )`

Comment: It sounds like the most sensible thing would be a `tf.reduce_logical_or()` op, by analogy with the other existing [reduction ops](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/math_ops.html#reduction). This doesn't exist at the moment, but we'd welcome contributions for it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do exactly what you want (directly from the documentation):

```
# 'x' is [[True,  True]
#         [False, False]]
tf.reduce_any(x) ==> True
tf.reduce_any(x, 0) ==> [True, True]
tf.reduce_any(x, 1) ==> [True, False]   <== this is what you need
```

https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/math_ops.html#reduce_any